# C# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'

Tags: c#

I get Error when try to set value for (a.Hinta ) to (HintaTextB.Text) in third code block.

```
    public bool saveAutoIntoDatabase(Auto newAuto)
    {
        bool palaute = false;

        if (connectDatabase())
        {
            string sql = "INSERT INTO [Auto] (Hinta, Rekisteri_paivamaara, Moottorin_tilavuus, Mittarilukema, VaritID)" +
                " VALUES (@Hinta, @Rekisteri_paivamaara, @Moottorin_tilavuus, @Mittarilukema, @VaritID)";

            cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, dbYhteys);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Hinta",SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = newAuto.Hinta;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Rekisteri_paivamaara", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = newAuto.Rekisteri_paivamaara;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Moottorin_tilavuus", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = newAuto.Moottorin_tilavuus;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Mittarilukema", SqlDbType.Int).Value = newAuto.Mittarilukema;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@VaritID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = newAuto.VaritID;

            
                
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


            disconnectDatabase();
        }
            
           return palaute;

        


    }
```

// *Controller class*

```
    public bool saveAuto(model.Auto newAuto)
    {
        bool didItGoIntoDatabase = dbModel.saveAutoIntoDatabase(newAuto);
        return didItGoIntoDatabase;
    }
```

I get Error whene try to set value for (a.Hinta ) to (HintaTextB.Text)
**Error,Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'.**

```
    private void saveButton_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Auto a = new Auto(0, 0, DateTime.Today, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);                        
        a.Hinta = HintaTextB.Text;
        a.Mittarilukema = mittarilukemaTextB.Text;            
        a.Rekisteri_paivamaara= dateTimePicker1.Value;
        a.VaritID = variComboBox.SelectedItem;
        bool aa = (logiikka.saveAuto(a));
    }
```

Comment: So what goes wrong? The database isn’t updated, you get an error, something else..?.

Comment: I have some problems with this... first of all .. what is the problem...???
second you might get your event handler wrong are you sure that the click event is on Clicl_1?
third you are assigning the values to the text box not the other way around...which leads to some null value to a copying on a null value (your third code block)

Answer (score 1):

your first two blocks of codes is ok
but in saveButton_Click_1 you call save with the default object values then assign object values to the control
you need first to assign controls values to the object then call save

```
a.Mittarilukema = mittarilukemaTextB.Text
```

then call save